# Text in span not appearing

Tags: javascript, if-statement, html

I have this function to generate random names from an array and then delete them so there are no duplicates. I want to add an if statement so that I can update another variable with a location name according to the name that was generated. When I add the if statement the name is never loaded in the span, without it, it works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanx for any help.

```
<h1> <span id="questionnum"></span>. Where was <span id="namequestion"></span> born?</h1>


<script type="text/javascript">


filenames = [ "Isaak Newton", "Johannes Gutenberg", "Christopher Columbus"];


generateName();
function generateName(){
filename = filenames.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*filenames.length), 1);
document.getElementById('namequestion').textContent = filename;

 if (filename == "Isaak Newton"){
     placeofbirth = "United Kingdom"; 
 }
 else if (filename == "Johannes Gutenberg"){
     placeofbirth = "Germany"; 
 }
 else  (filename == "Christopher Columbus"){
     placeofbirth = "Italy"; 
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Invalid syntax. Open your console. `else  (filename == "Christopher Columbus"){`

Comment: ^^ Lol ..  beat to the punch .. `else if  (filename == "Christopher Columbus"){` **or** `else {` ..  Can't have a condition on a `else`

Comment: as a side note, you really should group the data that belong together in logical objects, that would make your code more manageable, e.g. {name: "Isaak Newton", pob: "United Kingdom"}

Comment: I copied it from above and forgot to delete it. lol! I just couldn't see it..thanx!

Comment: @ timothee can u give me a link to find out more about that? haven't used it before. ty!

Comment: @niaoy: Read about objects at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects